# Exporting keys and values from two types of resx files into Excel c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, excel, c#-4.0

I'm new to C#.net and have created a program that reads the keys and values in specific resx files.  I have then done the same with a different set of corresponding resx files so that I can compare the matching keys to their values (which could be different or the same).  I have managed to write them to the console in visual studio, but would like to export the keys and values into an excel worksheet for comparison
I know that I need to use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace, but I dont know how to incorporate it into my program in visual studio, since i'm a newbie.  See code below...

```
        translations.Add(new TranslationEntry
                        {
                            key = d.Key.ToString(),
                            english = d.Value.ToString(),
                            welsh = match.Value.ToString()
                        });
        if (d.Value.ToString() != match.Value.ToString())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d.Key.ToString() + " - " + d.Value.ToString() + " - " + match.Value.ToString());
        }
        else
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(d.Key.ToString() + " - " + d.Value.ToString() + " - " + match.Value.ToString() + "Translation needed"); 
        }
    }
}
rsxr_en.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to work with Excel here is simple example:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
...

void Foo()
{
    Excel.Application ex = new Excel.Application(); //first of all - run it
    ex.Visible = true; //then - show it

    var workbook = ex.Workbooks.Add();
    var sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet; //in order to work with active sheet

    sheet.Cells[1, 1] = "some value"; //you can access cells with row index and column index
}
```

So, if you want to iterate through your data in a loop - you can insert it into excel using indexes. For example:

```
sheet.Cells[i, 1] = d.Key.ToString();
sheet.Cells[i, 2] = d.Value.ToString();
sheet.Cells[i, 3] = match.Value.ToString();

if (d.Value.ToString() == match.Value.ToString())
{
    sheet.Cells[i, 4] = "Translation needed"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually write the values to a .CSV (comma separated values) file. It is very easy to implement and opens nicely in excel.  Just write your strings surrounded by quotation marks and separated by commas to a text file which is named with the .csv extension. One line in the text file per row in excel. Sometimes I separate the values with tab `char(9)` characters instead of commas.

Otherwise if you wish to create proper excel files you could take a look at this high quality free library to write / read excel documents: http://epplus.codeplex.com/
We're using it in our application.

Hope this helps!